# Install debian package on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ruby

I want to install this on Ubuntu 10 or 11, any easy way to do that?

http://packages.debian.org/sid/ruby1.9.1-full

(related: I'm amazed that I can't find a third-party ubuntu package for ruby 1.9.2 -- is there one out there?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify *which* version of Ubuntu, which makes any sort of recommendation fairly meaningless (we can't even check that the package dependencies will be satisfied in Ubuntu).

If you're not running a version of Ubuntu that's fairly well in-sync with Debian sid, there's a fairly good chance that the package won't even install -- it'll require newer sonames of libraries than your Ubuntu release has, and that'll preclude the package from ever running successfully.  If the package dependencies *do* match, then it'll install, but might work right.  You can try it, but... yeah.  I wouldn't trust my production systems to it.

In general, it's not a good idea to try to install Debian packages in Ubuntu, and vice versa -- in cases where the packaging diverges, you're making a lot of work for yourself down the line because you're essentially running a completely untested upgrade path, which is likely to bite you in the butt.  In this case, you'll also be bereft of any sort of security updates or general improvements, which running sid packages, you might want.

A general word of caution: never, ever, *EVER* run any sort of `dpkg --force-<something>` command unless you know what you're doing (and if someone else is telling you do to it, by definition you don't know what you're doing).  It's the quickest route to a subtly broken system that you'll never be able to recover from.

Comment: whoops, added the version to the question now.

Answer (score -2):

You can compile it from source: just `./configure`, `make`, and `sudo make install`.

Comment: And you can just crush your nuts in a vice, but it's not a good look either.

Comment: If you are going to rebuild a package on Debian/Ubuntu it is almost always better to grab the source package from the repository and simply rebuild that.

Comment: Without starting a holy war, Debian-based distress (like Ubuntu) tend to do "things" to software - sticking with the package (or source package) usually leads to less pain and suffering in the long run...

Comment: Yeah, "things" like normalising the crack-smoking file locations upstream dreamed up, and providing a coherent policy to simplify systems administration.  The bastards.